# Python Hmac-SHA256 different output than expected

Tags: python, python-3.x, hmac

I had Python scripts that generate a signature to access the shopee API

Screenshot from Shopee documentation:
[image: Shopee documentation]

```
def verify_push_msg(self):

url = "https://partner.shopeemobile.com/api/v1/shop/get "
request_body = '{ "partner_id": 844103, "shopid": 30207467, "timestamp": 1579104428 }'
base_string = url + '|' + request_body

secret_key = <**SECRET KEY HERE**>

cal_auth = hmac.new(secret_key, bytes(base_string, 'latin-1'), hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()

print(cal_auth)
```

The output should be

> f6e26cccdb02d751219711f57e5db7d8d35f55a934244f4b67768dcc7b8ed7c8

But when I tried running that script I got

> c31c825412856d29400602655c5cdd3cf47638d7bd897b870988ee27ba7a5c6b

Whats wrong with my code?

(Sorry for my bad English).

Comment: Is the output timestamp-dependent? If so it should always generate a different value.

Comment: @AlexW: No HMAC depends on key and input text only, for the given fixed timestamp value it should be constant.

Comment: @AlexW yes it is, but i tried same parameters but different output from my python scripts. can you help me what mistake i am doing? thankyou

Comment: Are you sure, that there is no encoding issue in the secret_key setup? Try to use bytearray notation here e.g. `b'my secret key'`

Comment: Do you have an extra space terminating variable `url`? And/or extra spaces in `request_body`? Garbage in garbage out?

Comment: @guidot yeah i tried but still wrong output..@Booboo no, i tried remove the space but still wrong

Comment: This is slightly off-topic, but you could try using someone elses shoppee library? e.g. https://github.com/JimCurryWang/python-shopee